# What is ejb-client type in Maven POM?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

What is this element doing? I don't find any documentation or why you want to use that.

```
<type>ejb-client</type>
```

Comment: I thought you know how to Google: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/ejb-client-dependency.html

Answer (score 1):

As Shivan Raptor pointed it out, ejb-client type is "just" the result of the [maven-ear-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-ear-plugin).

Indeed it's a jar, that allow you to call remote [ejb](/questions/tagged/ejb), that you should distribute if you want te be called. The client for ejb calls ...

Everything is said ...

Butn please, don't said you didn't find anything. With maven+type+ejb-client, this is the first link ...

PS : Hopefully for you, I can't use a link towards Let me Google that for you ...